# A declarative workflow does not start automatically after you install Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Service Pack 1

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

That's the title of [kb947284](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947284) actually. Recently I was involved in a Sharepoint project. I run into this problem where **my workflow does not start automatically**. If I run the workflow **manually, it's just fine**. I found [kb947284](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947284). Apparently the cause of this problem is the installation of **WSS 3 SP1**. I did what it said in the Resolution section but it didn't work.

The Resolution said **to set the application pool account to use a different user account**. **What kind of different does it mean? What kind of user account will work?** I changed the user account but both old and new account is in the same group of administrator for the server where SP is installed.

Oh! I also found a copy of kb947284 and one comments stated there is already a hotfix ([kb956057](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/956057)). I've read the issues that are fixed but could not find anywhere about this workflow problem.

Could anyone please tell me how it's supposed to be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the KB:

This behavior occurs because a security fix in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP1 prevents declarative workflows from starting automatically under the system account. After you install Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP1, declarative workflows do not start automatically if the following conditions are true:

1. The Windows SharePoint Services Web
   application runs under a user's
   domain account.
2. The user logs in by using this
   domain account.
3. The site displays the user name as
   System Account. Back to the top

My Questions are:
Have you installed WSS SP1?

Are the 3 conditions stated above met?

If so, the application pool identity should be changed to one that isn't used by a person logging into SharePoint.

Comment: Your last line makes it clear for me. Thank you very much, Jason!